# Video not working on internet explorer 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My video works on all browsers except on IE6 and i don't know why it is happening.

My html file is this

```
        <div class="video_box">

            <div id="ytplayer"></div>
            <div class="video_ratio"></div>

            <div class="play_controls">
                <a href="#" class="play_pause"><span class="fa fa-pause"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="play_me_audio">Play with audio</a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

My JS file is this and i know it's right cause it works on other browser is ther anything i can do to make it work on internet explorer 6

```
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api?version=3";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            var player;
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',            
                playerVars: { 'rel':0 , 'loop':1, 'controls':0, 'start':0, 'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque','modestbranding':1,'showinfo':0,'playlist':'mjSLiluF_gk' },
                videoId: 'mjSLiluF_gk',
                events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}
                });
            }

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.mute();

                if(window['YOUTUBE_AUTOPLAY'] == undefined) window['YOUTUBE_AUTOPLAY'] = true;
                if(window['YOUTUBE_AUTOPLAY'] && !mobilecheck()) event.target.playVideo();

            }

            p_state = -1;

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
                p_state = event.data;
                switch (event.data)
                {
                    case 1:
                    case 3:
                    $('.play_pause .fa').addClass('fa-pause').removeClass('fa-play');
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    $('.play_pause .fa').addClass('fa-play').removeClass('fa-pause');
                    break;

                }
            }

            $('.play_me_audio').click(function(){                   
                if (player.isMuted())
                {
                player.unMute();
                $(this).text('Play muted');
                player.setLoop(['mjSLiluF_gk'],false);
                }
                else
                {
                $(this).text('Play with audio');
                player.mute();    
                }                       
                return false;
            });

            $('.play_pause').click(function(){               
                if (p_state == 1)
                {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
                if (p_state < 1 || p_state == 2)
                {
                    player.playVideo();
                }
                return false;                    
            });
```

Comment: You should not be adding support for ie 6... Nobody uses it

Comment: actually on our site logs it reaches almost 20k visits per month using ie6

Comment: IE6 is no longer supported by Google since 2010. But I know that some times you have to make it work... May I suggest you use Flash Player when the browser detected is IE6? That way, you would be running your video inside the plugin and would not struggle with the javascript in this WWII browser